# Change background color of HTML table cell depending on drop-down list value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.MRG{ background-color:#82E0AA; }
.MRA{ background-color:#F5B041; }
.MRR{ background-color:#EC7063; }
</style>
</header>
<body>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   <td>Made Ready</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
   <select>
  <option class="MRR">Red</option>
  <option class="MRA">Amber</option>
  <option class="MRG">Green</option>
   </select>
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an HTML table with a drop-down list populated in a HTML table cell.

The drop-down list has three options (Red, Amber and Green).

**I would like the background color of the HTML cell to change depending on the drop-down list value.**

For example. If drop-down list value is Green then HTML table cell background color will = green.

How would this be achievable by using JavaScript or CSS?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```js
document.querySelector('select').onchange=changeEventHandler;

var indicator = document.getElementById("color-indicator");

function changeEventHandler(event) {
    indicator.classList = this.value;
}
```

```css
.MRG{ background-color:#82E0AA; }
.MRA{ background-color:#F5B041; }
.MRR{ background-color:#EC7063; }
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   <td>Made Ready</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="color-indicator">
        <select>
          <option value="MRR">Red</option>
          <option value="MRA">Amber</option>
          <option value="MRG">Green</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you should ask, if jQuery is an option

Comment: OP's code has jquery include in it, although it should of been tagged with it as well

Comment: What do you mean ? If question is how to achieve this with jQuery ? (edited, removed jQuery)

Comment: @NicossB Sorry, I overlooked, that OP has already included jQuery. Take my upvote then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <html>
  <header>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </header>
  <body>
  <table  id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>Made Ready</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
      <select id="mySelect" onchange="abc()">
      <option value="red" class="MRR">Red</option>
      <option value="yellow"   class="MRA">Yellow</option>
      <option  value="green"  class="MRG">Green</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    function abc(){
        document.getElementById("myTable").style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("mySelect").value
    }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/95wvnh0x/7/

Answer (score 0):

Assign 'id's to your  and the target , then use something like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">...</select>
<td id="myCell">...</td>
<script>
    document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        document.getElementById('myCell').className = event.target.value;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With only three lines: 




    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .MRG{ background-color:#82E0AA; }
    .MRA{ background-color:#F5B041; }
    .MRR{ background-color:#EC7063; }
    </style>
    </header>
    <body>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
       <td>Made Ready</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<!-- Add class name for tr -->
        <tr class="changeColor">
          <td>
<!-- Add id  for select -->
       <select id="colorChanger">
      <option class="MRR">Red</option>
      <option class="MRA">Amber</option>
      <option class="MRG">Green</option>
       </select>
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<!-- Add this script -->
<script>
$('#colorChanger').on('change', function() {
$('.changeColor').addClass($('#colorChanger :selected').attr('class'));
});
</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```